# Alternate way to code multiple checks for NullPointerException, JAVA 8

Tags: java, java-8, null, conditional-statements, option-type

Is there any better way to code this in JAVA 8?

```
    if (info1 != null && info1.getId() != null && info1.getPartyNumber()!= null) {
        billing.setSenderId(info1.getId());
        billing.setSenderNumber(info1.getPartyNumber());
    }
    if (info2 != null && info2.getId() != null && info2.getPartyNumber()!= null) {
        billing.setReceiverId(info2.getId());
        billing.setSellerNumber(info2.getPartyNumber());            
    }

    ..
    ..
```

Thanks in advance.
Note: I looked into `Optional.ofNullable()` but not sure if that could really help here with multiple checks?

Comment: Is `info1.getId()` really allowed to be null?

Comment: in some corner cases.. yes.

Comment: you can also look into using a mapper like Orika. you just define the mapping of fields from one object to another and it does all the null checking for you.

Comment: What datatype is behind `info1.getId()`? If it is, as I would assume, a number type, it would make more sense to use a primitive type and initialize it with `-1` instead of using a Object type and initialize with `null`. This would eliminate the null check and avoid special treatment.

Comment: Appears to me that it is screaming for a (private? static?) method using a stream/optionals

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the best I could come up with. I'll let you decide if it's cleaner or not:

```
Optional<Info> oInfo1 = Optional.ofNullable(info1);
oInfo1.map(Info::getId).ifPresent(billing::setSenderId);
oInfo1.map(Info::getPartyNumber).ifPresent(billing::setSenderNumber);

Optional<Info> oInfo2 = Optional.ofNullable(info2);
oInfo2.map(Info::getId).ifPresent(billing::setReceiverId);
oInfo2.map(Info::getPartyNumber).ifPresent(billing::setSellerNumber);
```

Note that this is slightly different from the original in that it may set one field even if the other is null.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to rewrite it with `Optional` it could look like that:

```
Optional.ofNullable(info1)
.filter(i -> i.getId() != null)
.filter(i -> i.getPartyNumber() != null)
.ifPresent(i -> {
  billing.setSenderId(info1.getId());
  billing.setSenderNumber(info1.getPartyNumber());
});
```

### Edit

We process an `info1` only if it is not `null` and all conditions specified as `Optional.filter` parameters are matched. Thus only in case of `info1 != null` and `info1.getId() != null` and `info1.getPartyNumber() != null` the `Consumer` will be executed. That's an *alternate way to code multiple checks*. It does what your code does.

The same way applies to `info2`.

### Edit

The fluent API of `Optional` combined with a multi-line notation breaks every condition to an own line. IMO this makes the code easy to read and thus easy to understand. It keeps the simplicity, clarity of the original code as much as possible and still behaves in the same way.

Comment: This is uglier than the original, IMO.

Comment: @Lucio is it possible to set whatever is present. ex, if id is not null set id, if party number is not null set party number. the current code checks for both and only if both are not null, it sets.

Comment: @CuriousToKnow Have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52122731/2838289) of shmosel.

Comment: @Lucio/shmosel other than the difference said above, any other way your answers differ? I find shmosel way cleaner than Lucio but Lucio gets more votes for the answer. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @shmosel It's obviously longer than the original code. It illustrates how the code can be rewritten using `Optional`. I don't say, this is code is better than the original one.

Comment: @CuriousToKnow The code of my answer does the same as your code does. shmosel's answer will match your question you asked as comment above. But these are two different questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you copy code in your source you should always think twice. I think your testing is fine but i would make a method for it, so you code looks like this :

if ( isComplete(info1)
{
....
}
if ( isComplete(info2)
{
....
}

Answer (score 0):

If your multiple repetitions follow an exact pattern (ex. every odd repetition sets a `receiver`, else `sender`) or this pattern could be extracted to `Set<Integer>`, you can use `Map<Integer, Info>` where the key is an ID of `Info`, iterate through it and set only the selected items.

```
List<Info> list = ...                                             // List of Info
Map<Integer, Info> map = list.stream()                            // Stream
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)                                     // Filter null values
    .filter(i -> i.getId() != null && i.getPartyNumber() != null) // Filter null fields
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Info::getId, i -> i));              // Collect to Map<Integer, Info>

for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {                                        // The number of repetitions
    if (map.containsKey(i)) {                                     // If the ID was not filtered
        Info info = map.get(i);                                   // Get the Info
                                                                  // Here the pattern comes
        if (i % 2 == 0) {                                         // you can either compare with a
                                                                  // predefined Set of IDs
            billing.setSenderId(info.getId());                    
            billing.setSenderNumber(info.getPartyNumber());       // Sender
        } else { 
            billing.setReceiverId(info.getId());                  // Receiver
            billing.setSellerNumber(info.getPartyNumber());          
        }
    }
}
```

The solution will vary and depends on the number of possible settings alongside with `sender` and `receiver`. Also, calculation of pattern might be based on different logics - I recommend to validate against ex. `Set<Integer> senders` which will contain IDs suitable to be set as a sender, the same goes for the receiver and other possibilities.

- **Pros**:

  - Regardless of a number of `Info` iterated, the length of the solution remains the same (except collecting all the `Info`s to the input `list`).
  - Avoids bloat code and repetitions.
- **Cons**:

  - You have to think over the calculation and logics to distinguish what to be set.
  - Might look messy and hard to read.